# Super-fast screen scraping techniques?

Tags: html, screen-scraping

I often find myself needing to do some simple screen scraping for internal purposes (i.e. a third party service I use only publishes reports via HTML). I have at least two or three cases of this now. I could use apache httpclient and create all the necessary screen scraping code but it takes a while. Here is my usual process:

1. Open up Charles Proxy on the web site and see whats going on.
2. Start writing some java code using Apache HttpClient, dealing with cookies, multiple requests
3. use Jericho HTML to deal with parsing of the HTML.

I wish I could just "record my session" quickly and then parametrize the things that vary from session to session. Imagine just using Charles to grab all the request HTTP and then parametrize the relevant query string or post params. Voila I have a reusable http script.

Is there anything that does this already? I remember when I used to work at a big company there used to be a tool we used called Load Runner by Mercury Interactive that essentially had a nice way to record an http session and make it reusable (for testing purposes). That tool, unfortunately, is very expensive.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I think all of them were quite valuable and will help others facing the same dilemma. I decided to try Twill since it seems like a very easy language and because its in Python is cross-platform. Many of the tools suggested seemed good as well -- although a few seemed Windows-specific and others seemed like they had a steeper learning curve.

Answer (score 9):

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is a scriptable, headless browser written in Java. We use it for some extremely fault-heavy, complex web pages and it usually does a very good job.

To simplify things even more you can run it in Jython. The resultant program reads more like a transcript of how one might use a browser than hard work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention what you want to use this for;  One solution is to simply "script" your web browser using tools like Selenium if having a web browser repeat your actions is an acceptable solution. You can use the [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to record what you do and then alter the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

> I wish I could just "record my session" quickly and then parametrize the things that vary from session to session.

If you have Visual Studio test edition it's web test function does that exactly. If you aren't using VS or want a stand alone tool I have had great success with [OpenSpan](http://www.openspan.com). It is more than just web, it does windows apps, and java!

Answer (score 3):

Selenium would be my 1st pick, as the IDE lets you do a lot of things the easy way by "recording" a session for you. But, if you're not happy with what it provides, you can also use the Python module called [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to programmatically walk through a website.

Answer (score 2):

Python and Perl both have a module called Mechanize (WWW::Mechanize for perl) that makes it *easy* to do browser behavior programmaticly (filling out forms, handling cookies, etc).

So, Python + BeautifulSoup (great html/xml parser) + mechanize (browser functions) = super easy/fast scraper

Comment: Quick Question, 
Can Mechanize handle AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

I used DomInspector for manually inspecting the site of interest to parametrize it's structure. Then simple Apache HttpClient and hand-made parser using this parametrized structure. Basically I could extract any info from any site automatically with a little tweak of parameters.. It's similar to how SAX parser works, all you need to tell it is at what sequence of tags you want to start grabbing the data. For example, google have pretty standard format of search results.. So, you just run to the third occurrence of 'tab' and start getting text from the first 'div' up until the end '/div'

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer supports Browser Helper Objects (BHOs). They can access IE' HWND (window handle) and it's easy to scrape the pixels from there. The `IWebBrowser2` COM interface also gives you access to the HTTP requests, and you can get back the parsed HTML document via `IWebBrowser2::Document = IHTMLDocument / IHTMLDocument2 /IHTMLDocument3`

Answer (score 1):

Using FireFox, it should be possible to implement much of it with its powerful support for addons and enhancements, however that wouldn't really mean to run "headless", but really be a real scripted browser. Also, I seem to recall having read that google's chrome browser uses a similar technique to do automated regression testing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't personally vouch for it, but there is a free firefox plugin: DejaClick
I installed it the other day and did some remedial recording, playback, and script editing activities with it.  It pulled them off without much of a learning curve.  If your end goal is to show something in a web browser, then it should suffice.

They offer web transaction monitoring services, implying that you can export the scripts for other uses, but they may be too proprietary to use outside of your web browser / their paid service.

http://www.dejaclick.com/